# Dropdown Menu Does Not Show Up Whenever I Clicked The Toggle Icon and As I Navigate Downwards

Tags: html, css, navigation

This is coming from the W3Schools Code. I am having an issue regarding the drop-down menu function where it disappears or does not show whenever I clicked the toggle icon. Whenever I clicked the toggle icon, I would always go up to see the tabs.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_responsive_navbar_dropdown.asp

Here is the code:

HTML

```
  <!-- Responsive Top Navbar -->
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
        <a href="#news">News</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#about">About</a>
        <a class="topnav-right" href="#">Sign Up</a>
        <a class="topnav-right" href="#">Sign In</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
/* Navbar Top */

body {
margin:0;
font-family:Arial
}

.topnav {
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
width: 100%; /* Full width */
 }

.topnav a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
 }

 .active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
  }

  .topnav .icon {
   display: none;
   }



   .dropdown-content a {
   float: none;
   color: black;
   padding: 12px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
   display: block;
   text-align: left;
   }

  .topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  }

  .dropdown-content a:hover {
   background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
   }

  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
   display: block;
    }

   @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
   display: none;
   }


 .topnav a.icon {
 float: right;
 display: block;
 }
 }

  @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
 .topnav.responsive .icon {
 position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  }

 .topnav.responsive a {
  float: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
 }

.topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
.topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Make your question clear.

Comment: Pardon, I have now changed hoping it is now clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
1) Firstly, you need to include javascript.
and wrap the javascript inside the "script" as below :

 

    `<script>
      function myFunction() {
       var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
       if (x.className === "topnav") {
           x.className += " responsive";
          } 
       else {
          x.className = "topnav";
            }
       }
    </script>   
    `

2) Second, add before inside `<head>` this external library :
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"> `

3) Add some longer content to see if the toggle menu work well after scrolling down.
```

```js
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
      if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
      } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
      }
    }
```

```css
/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

/* Dropdown container - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* Style the dropdown button to fit inside the topnav */
.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Style the dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Style the links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

/* Add a dark background on topnav links and the dropdown button on hover */
.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

/* Add a grey background to dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu when the user moves the mouse over the dropdown button */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

/* When the screen is less than 600 pixels wide, hide all links, except for the first one ("Home"). Show the link that contains should open and close the topnav (.icon) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

/* The "responsive" class is added to the topnav with JavaScript when the user clicks on the icon. This class makes the topnav look good on small screens (display the links vertically instead of horizontally) */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```